# OpenVpn not working with Asus DSL-AC68U

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, azure

**Goal:** Change the network location(country) using vpn at my house.

**Why:** Vpn is much more secure than using proxy. It is integrated to the router. Do not want to use a shared solution such as a smart DNS solution or hidemyass.

**Problem:** Could establish Openvpn connection with my home router using openvpn server hosted at Azure. But can not browse pages.

**Debugging:**

- Vpn Client tells the connection is established.
- The home network could ping the server in Azure.
- Browsing gives "Dns probe finished error"

**Note:** The router works with Hidemyass service using L2TP. The reason I would like to use Azure is I need a dedicated resource.

**Misc:**

- Installed openVpn server both on Windows and Ubuntu.
- I have enabled the TCP and UDP ports in the Azure server and disabled
  the firewall.
- This config enables pinging from home network to Azure
  network. ( push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" )

**What did I Tried**

- Installed dns server on azure part
- Dns had forwarders configured
- Pointed home dns in azure
- Giving domain name removes one dns timeout when not connected to vpn.
- Disabled the firewall at home
- Ping to Azure gateway ip(10.8.0.1) works after vpn
- After vpn home network can access the files in (10.8.0.1) using \10.8.0.1\vpn ( after push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" )
- Ping to google ip(216.58.209.14) stops after vpn when we have push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" config. But I could ping azure
- Updated ip registry for enable ipforwarding on the Azure and restarted. Even the vpn connection seems working the ip forwarding does not work.

**All updates for the router**

http://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLAC68U/HelpDesk_Download/?utm_source=asus-product&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=router

**CONCEPTUAL NETWORK TOPOLOGY**

[image]

**REAL NETWORK TOPOLOGY**

[image]

**SERVER CONFIGURATION**

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\ca.crt"

cert "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\server.crt"

key "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\server.key"

dh "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\dh1024.pem"

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

**push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"**

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo

persist-key

persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 9

**CLIENT CONFIGURATION**

client

dev tun

proto udp

remote 40.121.143.153 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key

persist-tun

ca "C:\Vpn\ca.crt"

cert "C:\Vpn\mike-laptop.crt"

key "C:\Vpn\mike-laptop.key"

ns-cert-type server

comp-lzo

verb 9

**ERROR AT MY HOUSE BEFORE AFTER push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp**
[image]

**BEFORE AND AFTER VPN**
[image]

**ROUTING TABLE AT HOME**
[image]

**ROUTING TABLE AT AZURE**
[image]

**References:**

**Asus Router DSL-AC68U**

https://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLAC68U/

Comment: Can you please describe your problem better? We don't know what your openvpn configuration contains, we don't know your servers details (IP address, version of software running, ...), we don't know anything about your router configuration. Your screenshots don't contain any useful information.

Comment: Tonin thanks for the feedback. Just updated the post.

Comment: After reading this http://marguspala.com/simple-way-to-route-all-traffic-via-gateway-with-openvpn/

removed "redirect-gateway def1" from server to the client. We now do not get dns probe finished error but not using the gateway

Comment: If you disable `redirect-gateway def1` then your DNS probe is **not** using the VPN.

Comment: Moving this parameter on to the client config enables me to ping google from the client and also could ping azure. But the traffic does not go over vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the openvpn created a new network interface tap/tun. After telling the interface auto assign dns and ip address the issue was solved.Now connected via vpn.

[image]

Comment: Is everything solved ?

Comment: Other than performance it is working

Comment: It is worth noting: On Windows (as VPN server or client) the `Windows DHCP Client Service` is **required** to assign IP addresses to the Tun or Tap interface.

Comment: True for dns probing to work over

Comment: Performance problem solved after removing the debug parameters...But there is room to improve.

Answer (score 1):

This is one *possible* answer (not covered by your question):

- Enable `IP_Forwarding` on the Azure Server.

Use `Regedit`:

- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
- Select key `IPEnableRouter` `REG_DWORD`
- Modify value = `Hexadecimal` `1`
- Reboot server

Note: This Registry key may not be the same for your version of Windows but you will still need to make sure IP_Forwarding is enabled on your server.

Comment: tried that and it did not work.

Comment: So you had not enabled `IP_Forwarding` before hand ?

Comment: I phrased it wrong. After your post I tried it but it did not work. The vpn connects I could access the resources in the Azure and could ping azure but can not redirect my internet traffic to Azure.

Comment: Do you have access to `netsh.exe` on your Server machine ?

Comment: Yes. I am the local admin on that machine

Comment: As your VPN server is windows you cannot use `iptables` to perform NAT but you can use [NATHack](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/NatHack)